# Java 2D Game - rendering attack visuals for proper entities

Tags: java, animation, 2d, 2d-games

I have a question about rendering certain states for individual entities in my Java 2D Game.

The full code is at https://github.com/keloman/java2dproject/tree/master but I'll lay out the most important bits here

In my Player class,I have the following boolean variable:

```
// Checks if entity is hurt by player
public static boolean isHurt = false;
```

In the `checkAttacks()` method, `isHurt` is set to `true`

```
for (Entity e : handler.getWorld().getEntityManager().getEntities()) {
        if (e.equals(this)) {
           // Check if Entity is player 
           // So the player doesnt hurt himself when attacking
            continue; 
        }
        if (e.getCollisionBounds(0,0).intersects(aRectangle)) {
            isHurt = true;
            e.hurt(1);
            return;
        }
    }
```

In my Tree class, the `tick()` method is done like this:

```
@Override
public void tick() {
    if (Player.isHurt) {
        getCurrentAnimationFrame();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Player.isHurt = false;
            }
        },180);
    }

}
```

And it calls this method:

```
private BufferedImage getCurrentAnimationFrame() {   
       if (Player.isHurt) {  
          return treeHurtTwo.getCurrentFrame();
       } else {
           return treeTwo.getCurrentFrame();
       }

    }
```

The "hurt" state animation is returned properly and stays on screen long enough due to `Timer` and `TimerTask` but the problem is that it renders the hurt state on ALL trees instead of the tree being attacked by the player.

How can I make it so that it renders a hurt state ONLY on an entity currently being attacked by the player?

**EDIT:**
The entities in the game world are managed by a `EntityManager` class that stores the entities in an ArrayList structure.

```
 public ArrayList<Entity> entities;
```

They are then added to the game world in the `World` class like this

```
entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler,100,200));
entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler,200,200));
entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler,350,200));
entityManager.addEntity(new Rock(handler,400,450));
```

Comment: *"The full code is at ..//github..."* Most people won't follow links - all relevant code should be in the question *"but I'll lay out the most important bits here"* ..& by 'relevant' I mean a [mcve]. Add an MCVE as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: The problem is that it is all interconnected , I can't make an MCVE because that would mean at least a few classes of my game being included in the question. If I do that,my code would go over 300 lines of code and I don't think anybody would want to read that either.

Comment: *"that would mean at least a few classes of my game"* Extra classes can be included in an MCVE. It's just that the only `public` class must have the `main(..)` method. *"code would go over 300 lines"* I bet the problem could be expressed in less. I also bet that short an MCVE, this is not getting much attention. BTW - are Swing or AWT components used?

Comment: Both Swing and AWT components are used but mainly AWT. I did a patch-job solution of this using `instanceof` operator but it only works right when I have different class entities in my ArrayList. I was thinking about adding an `int uID` field in the constructor of the Entity class so that every entity must have a unique ID in the game world. I then take the `uID` of every entity in the `for () {}` loop and check it in the `if` condition of the `tick()` method of the entity.